# Como fazer o Outline dos botões acompanhar a curvatura dos elementos?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, acessibilidade

Sei que o `outline` é importantíssimo para a usabilidade e principalmente para a acessibilidade das página, inclusive aqui tem um artigo da WebAIM bem interessante sobre isso: https://webaim.org/blog/plague-of-outline-0/

Porém o `outline` parece não acompanhar o `border-radius` dos elementos. No caso desse botão por exemplo, veja que o `outline` não acompanha curvatura do elemento, causando um efeito indesejado...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderíamos tratar esse tipo de caso da forma mais correta possível, digo, qual a melhor prática para esse tipo de problema? Qual "paliativo" podemos usar sem comprometer a acessibilidade e usabilidade?

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O firefox possui a propriedade [`-moz-outline-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-outline-radius), porém não funcionará na maioria dos browsers

Uma solução seria desativar o `outline` e criar um próprio com `:focus`

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
button#ex1:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px lightblue;
}
button#ex2:focus {
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<button id="ex1">Button</button>
<button id="ex2">Button</button>
```

Uma informação importante do uso da propriedade `border` para simular o `outline` é que há uma alteração no tamanho dos elementos, por exemplo:

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
button:focus {
  border: 25px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<br>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<br>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
```

Conforme o próprio autor da pergunta comentou no chat:

*"Se vc entrar na página do google.com vc vai ver que ele tb usa a técnica que vc usou na resposta ;)"*

*"Tirando isso parece que border-radius + box-shadow consome muito recurso de renderização, principalmente quando animado!"*

*"No entando o próprio BS4 usa box-shadow para tratar esse 'outline'"*

*"... o [BS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) até muda a cor pra combinar com o btn"*